# faces semi-transparent in edit mode, revealing background plane

Tags: modeling

working on the hood of a car, I've been looking through the similar kind of questions here, couldn't find something that resembles my question.
So, how can I make faces a bit transparent (in solid view) in order to easily see the image background plane. It makes me kind of like forced to delete only the faces in order to see what I'm working with. (switching to wireframe view hides the plane)  Is there a easier way? Somewhere in the display mesh settings?
[image]

Thanks / Dan

Comment: If you are using background images, you have a "back/front" option which allows to choose if the background image is above or below your scene

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to have your reference image as a plane, you can also have it as a background which is visible in wireframe mode too. To do so you have to press <kbd>N</kbd> to open up the properties and then you have to scroll down to 'Background Images'. Check the box, click 'Add Image' and open up your Image. From there on you can modify the image the way you want like changing it's opacity or making it only visible from top view.

Another way of doing this is to change the maximum drawing type of your car hood to 'Wire' in the 'Object' tab (orange cube, then scroll down to display). This makes only the car hood appear in wire mod and everything else is in the mode you want e. g. Textured, so you can see through your hood but you can still see your background plane textured.

[image: the two ways of doing it I explained]

Comment: Similar thing is possible with empty/image which has transparency and can be put on top or below your model.

Comment: thanks everyone! especially thank you palkonimo for the full explanation! =)